# Meaning of "X is not worth the electrons it was transmitted with"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading a question ([Why is stigmata a plural of stigma?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536822/why-is-stigmata-a-plural-of-stigma/536866#536866)) and came across a phrase that I don't know what to do with or how to google it. I don't know its meaning.

It was used in a comment under "user121863" answer. The score of the comment is 31 and it reads:

> I'm not familiar with Grammarist, but if this article is representative, then it's a bad resource and you should stop referencing it. "Stigmata" is usually treated as plural (with singular "stigma"), as any dictionary will confirm; you will sometimes see "a stigmata", in the same way that you'll sometimes see "a bacteria" and "a criteria", but this is not as common as the standard usage, and **a page that suggests otherwise is not worth the electrons it was transmitted with.**

Can anyone tell me the meaning of the bold phrase please?

Comment: It's an extrapolation (probably a "one-off") from long-established *[this legal contract] **is not worth the paper it's written on*** (it's *totally* worthless, it has no "legal force" or "truth value"). Witty or lame, depending on your perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Not worth the paper it's printed on" is another way of saying "worthless", "of no value":

> **not worth the paper it's written/printed on** not of real value : not legally valid *This contract isn't worth the paper it's written/printed on.* ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/not%20worth%20the%20paper%20it%27s%20written%2Fprinted%20on))

Often the reference is to a lack of legal validity, but not always.

To say of a webpage that it is "not worth the electrons it was transmitted with" is a modern variant of the same idea - it is a way of saying that the advice or ideas on that webpage are worthless - that they have even less value than the energy that was used to transmit them.

Answer (score 0):

We speak of things being “worth X”, meaning that their value is (at least) X. We use it both in a literal sense (“that phone is worth the $500 that I paid for it”) or figurative (“his advice is worth its weight in gold”).

The negated version is usually used somewhat humorously (“that new guy isn’t worth a hill of beans”), and we enjoy finding strange things to compare a thing’s *lack of* value to. In your example, electrons are free, so saying that source’s advice isn’t even worth zero means it’s worse than no advice at all.

Comment: Interesting. A hill of beans would be worth a lot. I mean Heinz probably processes a hill of beans every year.